# How to flag an email sent using Python as Important?

Tags: python, smtplib

I am trying to send an email with the important flag (yellow box) marked. I  tried the following code. This works fine for Outlook, it marks the email as High Importance with "!" but I could not get it to work for regular Gmail to mark the importance flag. Any help is appreciated.

```
import os

EMAIL_ADDRESS = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
import imghdr

Email_addresses = ['example@gmail.com']
for email_address in Email_addresses:
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['X-Priority'] = '1'
    msg['X-MSMail-Priority'] =  'High'
    msg['Subject'] = '[Urgent!] Action Required!'
    msg['From'] = EMAIL_ADDRESS
    msg['To'] = email_address
    msg.set_content('This is a mail sent using python')

    files = ['01.png','02.jpg','03.png','04.png','05.png','06.png']
    for file in files:
        with open(file, 'rb') as f:
            file_data = f.read()
            file_name = f.name

        msg.add_attachment(file_data, maintype='application', subtype='octet-stream', filename=file_name)

    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
        smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)
        smtp.send_message(msg)
```

Another question I have is, is there a limit to the number of emails that can be sent?

Comment: The priority fields you are setting are nonstandard Microsoft extensions which no standard client pays much attention to. Perhaps Gmail have their own proprietary extensions.

Comment: You should only ask one question per question, please. SMTP doesn't place any restriction on how much you can send, but many providers have their own limits, for what should be obvious reasons, and of course ultimately bandwidth restricts how fast you can go.

Comment: Proper bulk email requires a lot more than the ability to send many emails, anyway. You want a managed service with their own email deliverability experts, unless you are planning to build the same expertise yourself and compete with them (from extremely humble beginnings, it seems).

Comment: Thank you. @tripleee Anything I can do about this? Do I have to look at Google API or sth?